# Problem with understanding the PERCENT_RANK function with ASC and DESC sorting

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with 5 rows. I want to answer the questions:

**a)** what % of employees earn more than 1500?

**b)** what % of employees earn less    than 1500?

The same query will give different answers, depending on the sorting used:

QUERY_**A (asc)**:  25% earns less than 1500, and 75% earns more that 1500

QUERY_**B (desc)**: 50% earns more than 1500, and 50% earns less than 1500

Which of these two queries will correctly answer questions a) and b)?

**query_A (asc):**

```
select salary, round( percent_rank() over(order by salary ASC), 2 ) * 100 as pct_asc
from emp_sal;

SALARY  PCT_ASC
----------------
1000     0
1500     25
1500     25
2000     75
3000     100
```

**query_B (desc):**

```
select salary, round( percent_rank() over(order by salary DESC), 2 ) * 100 as pct_desc
from emp_sal;

SALARY  PCT_DESC
----------------
3000     0
2000     25
1500     50
1500     50
1000     100
```

Answer (score 1):

> Which of these two queries will correctly answer questions a) and b)?

Neither. You can look at the sample data and see that one salary is below 1500, two equal 1500 and two are above 1500 which gives percentages of 20%, 40% and 40% respectively.

You can calculate it using:

```sql
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN salary < 1500 THEN 100 ELSE 0 END) AS percent_below_1500,
       AVG(CASE WHEN salary > 1500 THEN 100 ELSE 0 END) AS percent_above_1500
FROM   emp_sal;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE emp_sal (salary) AS
SELECT 1000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1500 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1500 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3000 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| PERCENT_BELOW_1500 | PERCENT_ABOVE_1500 |
| --- | --- |
| 20 | 40 |

---

Percent rank is ranking the results and then working out what percentile of the data that rank corresponds to:

```sql
SELECT salary,
       COUNT(*) OVER () AS cnt,
  
       RANK() OVER (ORDER BY salary ASC) AS rnk_asc,
       (RANK() OVER (ORDER BY salary ASC) - 1)
       / (COUNT(*) OVER () - 1) * 100 AS calc_pct_asc,
       PERCENT_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY salary ASC) * 100 AS pct_asc,
  
       RANK() OVER (ORDER BY salary DESC) AS rnk_desc,
       (RANK() OVER (ORDER BY salary DESC) - 1)
       / (COUNT(*) OVER () - 1) * 100 AS calc_pct_desc,
       PERCENT_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY salary DESC) * 100 AS pct_desc
FROM   emp_sal
ORDER BY salary;
```

Which outputs:

| SALARY | CNT | RNK_ASC | CALC_PCT_ASC | PCT_ASC | RNK_DESC | CALC_PCT_DESC | PCT_DESC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 5 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 5 | 100 | 100 |
| 1500 | 5 | 2 | 25 | 25 | 3 | 50 | 50 |
| 1500 | 5 | 2 | 25 | 25 | 3 | 50 | 50 |
| 2000 | 5 | 4 | 75 | 75 | 2 | 25 | 25 |
| 3000 | 5 | 5 | 100 | 100 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7gD5Bx5c)

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH TEMP AS
(
SELECT 1000 AS SAL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1500 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1500 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3000 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TEMP WHERE SAL>1500)/(select count(*) from temp))*100 as PER_EMP_GREATER_THAN_1500
    ,((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TEMP WHERE SAL<1500)/(select count(*) from temp))*100 as PER_EMP_LESSER_THAN_1500
FROM dual;
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**